# Quick Action on Opportunity not showing

Tags: page-layout, quickaction

I created a Quick Action on Opportunity that creates a task of a certain record type however it does not show up. I am not sure why?

Quick Action

[image]

Page Layout

[image]

Page

[image]

Comment: does the profile have access to that record type? Are you sure it's not using a lightning page + dynamic actions?

Comment: I cannot see it as system admin. No dynamic actions. I am also on the correct page layout when viewing.

Comment: Even as System admin, if you don't have the record type added then you will not see a quick action based on that record type. If you go to `Setup --> Profiles --> System Administrator --> Record Type Setting --> See that the record type is under Task`

Comment: I checked it has access

Comment: You could go into your ` Setup --> Session Settings` and turn off `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance`. That should allow you to refresh (CTRL + F5) and see the latest changes in hopes it just hasn't propagated yet. To be really certain, you can drag some other random action onto the layout to check you're getting the latest and on the right layout. Otherwise, not much else to check - might just be worth re-doing the QA in a different sandbox to see if you run into the same issue.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the Opp object? I have created Quick Actions before. In fact if I create a Quick action that is a LWC this shows up on the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was creating a quick action to create a Task on the Opportunity record. This apparently will not show on the Record page and will show on the Activity View.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_records_record_activities_view.htm&type=5